# Rails query param in URL twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a search form that searches a geocoded model called property. The geocode search works fine. However when I introduce more params to the search it returns incorrect results.

I have two boolean columns on the property model, smokers and pets. In my URL I notice that the same query param for pets is inserted twice:

http://localhost:3000/properties?utf8=%E2%9C%93&location=L17+6DD&distance=10&pets=false&pets=true&smokers=false&commit=Search

I'm using Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0 and PostgreSQL

Search form:

```
<%= form_tag properties_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= label :location, "Search properties near : " %>
    <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location] %>

    <%= label :distance, "Distance : " %>
    <%= text_field_tag :distance, params[:distance] %>

    <%= label :pets, "Pets : " %>
    <%=hidden_field_tag 'pets', false%>
    <%=check_box_tag 'pets', true %>
    <%= label :smokers, "Smokers : " %>
    <%=hidden_field_tag 'smokers', false%>
    <%=check_box_tag 'smokers', true %>

    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Properties controller action:

```
def index
if params[:location].present?
  @properties = Property.near(params[:location], params[:distance] || 10)
                    .where("pets = :pets", {pets: params[:pets]})
                    .where("smokers = :smokers", {smokers: params[:smokers]})

else
  @properties = Property.all
end
```

end

Comment: You need to remove   `<%=hidden_field_tag 'pets', false%>`

Comment: I tried this, but the if the check box is not checked it is sending a null value instead of false, which breaks my search.

Comment: Then create a scope for pets e.t.c. `scope :pets, ->(pets){ where(pets: pets) if pets.present? }` then `Property.pets(params[:pets])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the hidden field tags :

```
<%=hidden_field_tag 'pets', false%>
<%=hidden_field_tag 'smokers', false%>
```

For null value issue use this :

```
<%= check_box_tag 'pets', 'boolean_attribute', {}, 'true', 'false' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'smokers', 'boolean_attribute', {}, 'true', 'false' %>
```

OR leave your form as it is manage params in controller like :

```
@properties = Property.near(params[:location], params[:distance] || 10)
                    .where("pets = :pets", {pets: params[:pets] || false})
                    .where("smokers = :smokers", {smokers: params[:smokers] || false})
```

Comment: No, that errors out: "wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..4)"